# Doctrine: From SQL to DQL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've been trying to do a regular query with an inner join in Doctrine's DQL but with little success:

SQL:

```
SELECT 
    r.rtsRate
FROM tmc_rates_tbl_rts as r
INNER JOIN tmc_business_rel_buz as b ON (b.buzPcsID = r.rtsBuzID AND b.buzCmrID = r.rtsCmrID)
WHERE b.buzID = :business
AND r.rtsProID = :user;
```

DQL:

```
$qb = $this->rateRepo->createQueryBuilder('r')
            ->select('r.rate')
            ->innerJoin('r.business', 'business')
            ->where('r.business = :bid')
            ->andWhere('r.user = :user')
            ->setParameter('bid', $time->getBusiness())
            ->setParameter('user', $this->user)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
```

Doctrine cames out with a double join out of the blue:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0_.rtsRate AS rtsRate_0 FROM tmc_rates_tbl_rts t0_ INNER JOIN rate_business r2_ ON t0_.id = r2_.rate_id INNER JOIN tmc_business_rel_buz t1_ ON t1_.id = r2_.business_id AND (t1_.buzStatus = 1) WHERE t1_.buzID = ? AND t0_.rtsProID = ?' with params [9, 5]:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'tm_salesn.rate_business' doesn't exist

500 Internal Server Error - TableNotFoundException
```

I very much appreciate any help

Comment: How does your entity look (with mapping)? Just fyi you're asking about the Query Builder, DQL is the SQLish query language you can optionally use.

Comment: Please post your Doctrine configuration of your *rate* and *business* entities